# What other alien planet was Hulk on?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Ragnarok*, Thor says Sakaar is the second alien planet Banner had been on. What was the first?

Comment: No, he said he had only been in one planet before (rather than one "alien" planet), meaning Earth, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I remembered, he said second planet, not second alien planet. So first planet is Earth.

Comment: Ok, I must have misheard.  Thank you.

Comment: Of course, earth is an alien planet to Thor.

Answer (score 12):

The actual quote is

> **Banner:** *Calm? I'm on an alien planet*
>
> **Thor:** *It's just a planet. You've been on a planet before*
>
> **Banner:** *Yeah, one.*
>
> **Thor:** *Well, now you've been on two.*
>
> <sub><sup>*Transcription mine*</sup></sub>

So the clear implication is that the *one* planet that he's already been on is Earth, with Sakaar being only his second.